# How to call a function from an array of functions

Tags: python, arrays, function, vector

What I want to do is to have an function called from an array of function. I did my homework and came across this stackOverflow question.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549292/in-python-how-do-i-run-an-array-of-functions](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

However the code offered in it works for calling all the functions in the array in turn. What I would like to do is to call just one function in the array depending on the array index. What I would call in assembly terms "a vectored jump to a subroutine".

I am using Circuit Python on a RP2040

Here is the code:-

```py
def one():
    print("One")

def two():
    print("Two")

def three():
    print("Three")

arr = (one,two,three)


for fnc in arr:
    fnc()
```

This runs through each function in turn

However what I would like to do is to call just one function depending on an array index. Something like "call function arr[i]

Comment: you don't need a loop to do that. just do arr[i]()

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I have been trying all sorts of variation of the same idea but was getting the syntax wrong.

Comment: your link doesn't direct me to a question, but instead to my homepage

Comment: BTW, `(one,two,three)` is not an array (*list*). It is a tuple. Quite important difference, even though it works the same in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A function will be called with just

```
List[k]()
```

So just use a for loop if you really need it, or call them individually when needeed.